# Access value of variable whose name is stored in another variable

Tags: c#, variables, variable-assignment

Using C#, is it possible to access the content of a variable whose name is stored in another string variable?

eg.

```
string str ="ABCDEFG";
string variable = "str";
```

How could I access the value of `str` using `variable`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Use Reflection for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably can, but that's too complicated.   Have you thought of using the Dictionary class?

```
Dictionary<string,string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();

myDictionary["str"] = "ABCDEF";

var valueinstr = myDictionary["str"];
```

Comment: what if the datatypes are different?

Comment: you can use a HashTable then.   That stores objects.

Comment: @JasonDam: Can't he use `Dictionary<object, object>`?

Comment: yes he can, depending on the number of elements, using dictionary vs hash will be more or less the same, performance not considering.  For the purist, Dictionary<object,object> will do an extra boxing/unboxing on the string.  Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by using reflection.

```
var fieldInfo = this.GetType().GetField(variable);
string theValue = (string)fieldInfo.GetValue(this);
```

With the reflection approach you get an object that describes the property, then you use it to retrieve the value from a specific instance of a class. If your property is not public then you will have to specify the correct [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) when you get the [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo). If you are using a variable like in your example then you need to retrieve a [FieldInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.aspx#Y2430) object ([another example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx#Y0)).

Comment: @slugster am getting the error: Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method or static field initializer

Comment: @Rohit then use `typeof(MyClass)` instead of `this.GetType()` as you cannot use `this` in a static class.