# Assigning a value to a variable which is stored in another variable

Tags: c#

I am looking for some direction in this code.

What I have is 2 variables:

1) CalcTimeDown - a string variable in a for loop which takes various values which correspond to another string variable for each value in the for loop

Initial value is a string - "CalculationTimeDown".  This gets suffixed by 000, 001, 002 and 003 and 004 giving me CalculationTimeDown000, CalculationTimeDown001, CalculationTimeDown002..etc

2) CalculationTimeDown000, CalculationTimeDown001, CalculationTimeDown002..etc are "id" in an XML Layout.  And should get values of 00:00, 00:30, 01:00... etc.

What I am trying to do is:

1. Loop in the *for loop* from 0 to 4.
2. Set values to the variable CalcTimeDown to CalculationTimeDown000,
   CalculationTimeDown001, ..... etc.
3. **Load variable CalculationTimeDown000 with "00:00"**
4. **Load variable CalculationTimeDown001 with "00:30"**
5. **Load variable CalculationTimeDown002 with "01:00"**
6. **Load variable CalculationTimeDown003 with "00:30"**
7. **Load variable CalculationTimeDown004 with "02:00"**

The Bold step above is what I am unable to accomplish - can someone guide me?

```
        // Assemble the variable name 
        this.CalcTimeDownInitial = "CalculationTimeDown";

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            // Assemble the variable name 
            this.CalcTimeDown = this.CalcTimeDownInitial + i.ToString("000");

            var TimeSlotVariable = new StringtoVariable(CalcTimeDown);

            this.iSlot = (i) * 30;
            //

            // Get the time to be pumped
            DateTime TimeSlotValue = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(this.iSlot);
            //


            // CalcTimeDown contains the variable name where I want to pump the value of TimeSlotValue
            // TimeSlotValue contains 00:00, 00:30, 01:00 etc.
```

//INCORRECT SYNTAX - HELP HERE PLEASE.

```
            TimeSlotVariable = TimeSlotValue;
```

Thank you in advance.

Uttam

PS: I could not find an example using Reflection which I could adapt for my use in the example above - hence this posting.

-------Edit added to explain difference------

This edit to explain how my question is different from the possible duplicate:

That question was about Accessing the value - the value is already loaded in that case.

My question is about loading a value - loading the value is what I am trying to accomplish.

Could you please remove the vote down, if my explanation is reasonable?  Thanks!

Comment: why not array or list instead of `CalculationTimeDown000, CalculationTimeDown001, CalculationTimeDown002..etc ` that will solve your issue in seconds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access value of variable whose name is stored in another variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119232/access-value-of-variable-whose-name-is-stored-in-another-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in creating variable names dynamically to store values in - if you can even get such a thing to work in C#. I've seen others try to do the same thing, but all they usually need is a collection.

Store each value in a `List<T>` where T is just the type of your data.

```
var timeSlotValues = new List<DateTime>();

for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    timeSlotValues.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i * 30));
}
```

I assume you'll eventually use this in a dropdown or something - you can just assign the list to the control as its data source.

---

And because I'm a LINQ enthusiast, I'll throw this in as an alternative solution:

```
var timeSlotValues = Enumerable.Range(0,5)
                               .Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i * 30))
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Grant Winney - I will be able to work this out from your suggestion.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dictionary to hold the key,value pairs like this:

```
        string varname = "CalculationTimeDown";

        Dictionary<string, DateTime> values = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            // Assemble the variable name 
            values.Add(varname + i.ToString("000"), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes((i) * 30));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating variables dynamically is not possible in c# as it is a strongly typed language. You can use dictionary in this case.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, DateTime> variables = new Dictionary<string,     DateTime>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            variables.Add(String.Format("CalculationTimeDown{0}", i.ToString("000")), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i * 30));
        }
    }
}
```